# Выбор только одного checkbox (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

Нужно сделать список чекбоксов, но выбирать можно только один из них.

```
onCheckPage = (item) => {
let exist = this.state.formData.category && this.state.formData.category.id === item.id;
if (exist) {
  this.state.formData.category = null;
} else {
  this.state.formData.category = item;
}};

isChecked = (id) => {
if (this.state.formData.category) {
  return this.state.formData.category.id === id;
} else {
  return false;
}};

let categoriesList = this.props.categories.map((item) => (
  <CategoryItem key={item.id} item={item} onCheck={this.onCheckPage} isChecked={this.isChecked(item.id)}
                role={this.props.role}/>
));
```

Comment: Я не силен в react. `this.onCheckPage` - разве не надо вызвать и передать туда `item`?

Comment: уточни что именно не получается? ты хочешь что бы один был активный остальные не активные? где компонент CategoryItem?

Comment: @LevShportak да, Чтобы было возможно выбрать только один CategoryItem, то есть чекбокс

Comment: посмотри тут, похожий случай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1313705/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/1313748#1313748

Comment: @LevShportak вообще не то

Comment: @LevShportak там они становятся неактивными, а мне надо, чтобы можно было выбрать только один чекбокс с возможностью смены, но чтобы было выбрано не больше одного

Comment: я ведь написал что похожий, нужно чуток переделать, но логика таже даже проще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно хранить состояние активного чекбокса в родительском компоненте, и далее  чекбок отмечается если он активный. Примерно так:

```js
// import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [activeCheckbox, setActiveCheckbox] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(10)].map((_, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <label>Checkbox {idx}</label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={idx === activeCheckbox}
            onClick={() => setActiveCheckbox(idx)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Можно добавить код чтобы можно было убирать выделение с текущего чекбокса.

Comment: чем это отличается от предыдущего ответа?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно работать

```
state = {
    checkedId:''
}   

setCheckedId = (id) => {
   this.setState({ checkedId: id})
};
let categoriesList = this.props.categories.map((item) => (
  <CategoryItem key={item.id} item={item} onCheck={this.setCheckedId} checkedId={this.state.checkedId}
                role={this.props.role}/>


const CategoryItem = ({ item, onCheck, role, checkedId}) => {

const isCurrentChecked = item.id === checkedId

  return (
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={()=> onCheck(item.id)}
        checked={isCurrentChecked }
      />
  );
};
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что компоненты это разные классы и при изменении одного из компонентов (чекбокса) другой не меняет свое состояние. Здесь нужно реализовать через handle, но как - ума не приложу

Comment: не понятна проблема, ты опиши подробнее тогда, изначально все чекбоксы ===false, потом ты нажимаешь на один, его id передается в родительский стэйт и возвращается назад во все компоненты чекбоксов, и в каждом проверяется на соответствие и только тот у которого такой же id будет true, остальные останутся  false

Comment: При решении, что описано выше, при активации чекбокса другой, ранее активированный, остается активным, т.к. не понимает, когда меняются состояния других